# Send uploaded JSON file to GraphQL in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I currently have the code below in React where I can upload a JSON file and it will display what has been uploaded but I would like to send this file to GraphQL via Apollo Server. The majority of the information that I have found through my research has been about sending images/pictures to GraphQL, which is not what I want to do, as I want the information inside the file to be sent. Is there a way to do this?

```
function App ({ children }) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      console.log("e.target.result", e.target.result);
      setFiles(e.target.result);
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className = "results">
      <h1>JSON Uploader</h1>
      <p>Upload a JSON file</p>
    <form>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button type="submit">Submit Data</button>
      
      {"uploaded file content -- " + files}
     
    </form>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have an `onSubmit` function?

Comment: No I don't currently have one, so at the moment when I click submit it just refreshes the page

Comment: Create one, and that's where you want to store the logic to upload the files from the state object. Use `e.preventDefault` to prevent page refresh.